# TypeError: SnowballStemmer.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytest

**function2.py**

```py
import string
from collections import Counter
from nltk.stem import *
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

def getNumberOfUppercaseWords(_list):
    n = 0
    for elem in _list:
        l = len(elem) 
        u = sum(c.isupper() for c in elem)       
        if u==l:
            n+=1
    return n

try:
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
    file = open('SMSSpamCollection', 'r')
    for line in file: 
        counter = Counter(line)
        number_of_character = len(line)
        number_of_dollars = counter['$'] 
        number_of_numeric = sum(c.isdigit() for c in line)
        line = line.translate(str.maketrans('.,;:/?!@#$&~#{([|-_^)]+=}*%', '         
'))
        tokens = line.split() 
        number_of_uppercase_word = getNumberOfUppercaseWords(tokens)        
        tokens = [stemmer.stem(token.lower()) for token in tokens] 
        tokens.insert(0,number_of_character) 
        tokens.insert(1,number_of_dollars) 
        tokens.insert(2,number_of_numeric) 
        tokens.insert(3,number_of_uppercase_word) 

except Exception as e:
    print('Error: ' + str(e))
```

**test_function2.py**

```py
from fungsi2 import *

def test_print_name():
    name = 'Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...'
    data = {'name': name}
    file = SnowballStemmer(data=Counter(return_value=data), args=data)

    # Call tested function
    assert getNumberOfUppercaseWords(file) == 'Hello {}!'.format(name)
```

**I just wanna build the pytest module and how I can call any function from function2.py anyone can help?**

Comment: Why are you comparing a number to a string in your assert? And what is your actual question? I'm having trouble to understand it.

Comment: i just want to call function and test it from function2.py and how I can call that?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to import and call a function in Python?

Comment: yes sir, cause i wanna test it the function and what the script look like?

Comment: It looks like you are new to Python - I would advice to familiarize yourself with the language first, otherwise it will take you ages to get something done.